# Best way to link UIView and UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Simple question: I am creating an iOS app and the view controller calculates some coordinates that it should pass to the view.  I am using the UIView's `drawRect` method, so my question is how should I send data to the view?  I am aware of delegates and NSNotificationCenter, but I feel like there should be a simpler way since this is a part of model-view-controller. If not, then that is OK, I was just wondering. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would declare properties in UIView, and change the values from UIViewController if anything needs to be changed.

Comment: Thanks! I knew there would be a simpler way. One other question, however, is how do I set the values from the UIViewController? I have a subclass of UIView that is connected to the view but calling `[self.view doSomething]` returns an error. Should I just create an instance of the UIView and set the values of that? Or should I say something like `self.view = instanceOfUIView`?

Comment: The default `view` property provided by `UIViewController` is not able to add new property to it. You need to use a subclass instance of `UIView` with your properties and add the instance as a subview to the default view of UIViewController instance. `[self.view addSubview:instanceOfUIView];`

Comment: @Peter's method should certainly work. But I am not sure what kind of error you encountered. If self.view is already an instance of UIView subclass and the subclass has a method named "doSomething", then [(SubClassName *)self.view doSomething] should certainly work. Is it what you tried? What is the error you saw then?

Comment: Thank you barley that worked perfectly! I already had a UIView subclass I just didn't know that I should cast `self.view` to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

User a property or a method in you UIView subclass. If your change requires a manual redraw of the view, make sure to call [self setNeedsDisplay] at some point.

Delegate or NSNotificaitonCenter is definitely overkill in this case. Since the UIViewController will presumably keep a pointer to the UIView, it's much simpler to directly interact with your view.